# How to get values from IXLCells (OpenXML)

Tags: closedxml

I want to find the cell in an Excel sheet that contains a certain text using closedXML. I use the following command:

`IXLCells RefCells =PortfolioWorksheet.Search(strInternalReference, CompareOptions.None, false);`

Accoridng to the Watch window in Visual Studio, RefCells does contain the correct cell address: C8 in my case.

I tried obtaining this value with:

`RefCells.First().GetValue<string>()`

Unfortunately I get the string I searched for and not the cell address.

Hope you can help!

Bas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetValue()` returns the content (value) of the cell. To get the address use `Address.ToString()` to get the full address or `Address.RowNumber` and `Address.ColumnLetter` (or `Address.ColumnNumber`) to get its parts.

Comment: To be clear, it would be `RefCells.First().Address.ToString()`